# How do I control what to publish as Facebook Instant Articles?

Tags: 7, views, social-network

I am using this [Facebook Instant Articles](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_instant_articles) module to integrate articles being published as Instant articles on Facebook. I have successfully tried to publish instant articles using the *RSS Feed* and *Views* modules.

When I look at the preview of the feed, the articles being added on the feed are all the articles recently published. This is not what I want. I checked the configuration, and I found out that I have to select each article.

Now, after doing this, I still can't filter out the articles which are selected to be published as instant articles. I tried adding a filter, but I can't add a Filter on my view. I have not yet added custom codes just via the administrative dashboard.

What I want is to freely filter out specific articles I want to publish as instant articles. In my case, the articles processed from the feed are the latest ones; if I edit an article to add it as instant article, it won't be shown.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score -2):

You can for example add a taxonomy to the articles and filter by that in the view.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Unfortunately, your short and unspecific answer will not be very helpful for beginners to achieve a suitable solution to the questioned problem. This group is intended to help the questioners and further visitors with similar problems. Please provide some more details, add to-the-point code examples/citations, and - if applicable - provide links for further reading. This will make your answer a great help.